# Don't find manage.py file in django project

Tags: django

I download django app from github but cant find manage.py file
the app link is [1](https://github.com/qubird/django-chatrooms)
it don't even have settings file so that I do some edit in INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
django-admin startproject newchat
```

and then use the downloaded directory like you would a normal app

Comment: It makes a new webapp than how can I relate downloaded app with this app. I am a beginner with python so will you tell me briefly...